# UI is not updating after Protocol call Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, protocols, viper

I was trying to implement viper architecture on my Xcode. I am following an article https://medium.com/cr8resume/viper-architecture-for-ios-project-with-simple-demo-example-7a07321dbd29.

also, I downloaded the article source code, and run well also UI is changing. but when I created a new project with swift 5 and copy all methods and classes. after running UI is not updating but both codes are the same. please check below

> This is a single-page sample code

please check this Github for my project https://github.com/Faizulkarim/movieHut/tree/main/MovieHutWithViper

This is my protocol

```
 protocol PresenterToViewProtocol: AnyObject{
func showMovieList(MovieList: Array<movieModel>)

 }
```

Here o call showMovieListMethod

```
extension MoviePresenter : InteractorToPresenterProtocol {
func movieFetchSuccess(movieModelArray: Array<movieModel>) {
    view?.showMovieList(MovieList: movieModelArray)
  }

}
```

// on MovieListViewController  confirmed delegate

```
extension MovieListViewController:PresenterToViewProtocol{
func showMovieList(MovieList: Array<movieModel>) {
        self.Movies = MovieList
         self.cover.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
         print(self.movies.count)
        self.trandingTableView.reloadData()
 }
}
```

on showMovieList function call, it's printing the total count of movies. But when I reloadtableview() table view is not interacting is showing any data. Even when I set to change the background of a view it's not changing. when I set breakpoint is' stop. So protocol is called properly but UI is not updating. i search in google didn't find relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be in a background thread. You can only update UI from main thread.

Try to update like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.trandingTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: i try with this but not working